# How to create a bat file to create folder on share and copy specific folders contents of all user profiles

Tags: windows-xp, backup

I am trying to create a batch file to create a network folder based on computer name and then copy the desktop, My Documents, Favorites from each profile to that share. So destination should be something like this: `\\server\share\computername\profile name\Mydocuments`, etc.

I can create the computername dir. but nothing copies.
I have tried this....

```
@echo off
md \\servername\sharename\profile backups\%computername%
cd C:\Documents and Settings
xCopy "\%%\Desktop" \\servername\sharename\profile backups\%computername% "%computername%\%%\*.*"
```

I have tried a few different methods but can never get them to copy to the share.. it needs to read the variable computername so i dont have to manually type it. Please help

Comment: I also need it t read the variable userprofile name

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing some variable names.

In the code supplied:  Replace the first `%%` with `%homepath%`, and replace the second one with `%username%`

Since `%homepath%` includes the "C:\documents and settings\" part, you don't need to change to that directory first.

Also encapsulate any paths that contain spaces (or potentially contain spaces) with quotes.

Lastly, consider using use XCopy's switches to [copy the assigned permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323007) as well.

```
@echo off
md "\\servername\sharename\profile backups\%computername%"
xcopy "\%homepath%\Desktop" \\servername\sharename\profile backups\%computername% "%computername%\%username%\" /O /X /E /H /K
```

Comment: Okay that helped however I need the script to copy and create each profile dir. The %username% argument only copies the logged on user.

Comment: Then you'll need to expand the script to include a loop, which iterates though a list of profiles. Getting that list can also be scripted by taking the info from a directory listing which contains all the profiles.  Based on that, you'd probably be better off aiming to do this in PowerShell (or VBS).

Comment: no need for a difficult script - just copy the entire "c:\documents and settings\" directory to the server? If all the computer DNS names are different then you could place the profiles in a folder on the server first by "mkdir \\servername\share\%computername%" - Also, robocopy is far better for tasks like this as it uses UNC names rather than drive letters.

Comment: ***Cacls*** (not to be confused with *calc*) can also be used for privileges and sharing.